# Parse json encoded array and fetch values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to parse these JSon array am getting from `json_encode(arr)`, the output is:

```
[{"id":"44","data":"[[10],[27],[13]]","_types":"ff"},  {"id":"44","data":"[[140],[327],[213]]","_types":"44f"}]
```

I need to iterate this using java script and fetch each values.
Am getting an error, Unexpected token.

Comment: `JSON.parse(inputStr)` should do

Comment: If json.parse() doesnt work, please show us your code where you try to fetch

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. What do you want to do (example)?

Comment: When i do json.parse am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N.I need to fetch each user ids and data from this json.

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: When i add single codes to this array in beginning and end of array manually, the json.parse works

Comment: actually am fetching the array from database, when i console it the json_encode($arr) has no single codes, so i couldnot parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a string, you simply need to do `JSON.parse`

```
var str = '[{"id":"44","data":"[[10],[27],[13]]","_types":"ff"},  {"id":"44","data":"[[140],[327],[213]]","_types":"44f"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse( str );

alert( obj[0].id );
```

Comment: there is no single codes in my json_enode($arr) output.Am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator  when i tried this

Comment: @user263371 my code doesn't have any `in` operator. I wonder why got the error you got. Can you share a fiddle? Or can you update the OP to show the code that you have tried?

Comment: the code you have provided is working, but the json assigned to str is in single codes right?my json output doesnt has single codes i cannot apply json.parse to str..

Comment: @user263371 can you share the exact JSON string you are testing with in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting array of java script object,i think you don't need to parse this.Just iterate this and fetch the result like below.

```
var q = [{"id":"44","data":"[[10],[27],[13]]","_types":"ff"},  {"id":"44","data":"[[140],[327],[213]]","_types":"44f"}];

 q.forEach(function(i){console.log(i.id)});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!